# How can i set active class on top li if i click to any child item

Tags: jquery, html

i have dynamic php menu from database similar like this html structure.

If i click to LED TV or TV CATEGORIES i wanna set active class to ALL CATEGORIES like this: dropdown-item dropdown-toggle active

how can i do that in php or jquery?

```
<li class="dropdown"><a id="20" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle " href="index.php?page=AllCategories&categoriesgroup=allcategoriesgroup"> ALL CATEGORIES<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="dropdown-submenu dropdown-reverse"><a id="402" class="dropdown-item" href="index.php?page=productCategories&categories=tvcategories">TV CATEGORIES<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li class=""><a id="403" class="dropdown-item" href="index.php?page=productDetail&product=ledtv">LED TV</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: for me to best solution is to get the categories type from url using get method and set condition according to that in your page. 
for ex: <? if($_GET['categories'] == 'categories=tvcategories') { $class = 'active'; }  ?>

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.parents("li").last()` to get the top li.

```
$(".dropdown-item").click(function() {
  $(this).parents("li").last().toggleClass("active");
});
```

```js
$(".dropdown-item").click(function() {
  $(this).parents("li").last().toggleClass("active");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown"><a id="20" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle " href="#"> ALL CATEGORIES<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="dropdown-submenu dropdown-reverse"><a id="402" class="dropdown-item" href="#">TV CATEGORIES<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class=""><a id="403" class="dropdown-item" href="#">LED TV</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you but this is not working on me. But when i click to link page is refreshing and then active class is removing? is it?

Comment: @DoganOzer That changes everything, you need it to stay after page refresh, basic then you need to look at localStorage

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.test', function () {
  var newids=$(this).data('id');
  $(this).parents().children('#'+newids).addClass("active");
 });
```

```css
.active{
color:red !important; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown"><a id="20" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle " href="#"> ALL CATEGORIES<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <li class="dropdown-submenu dropdown-reverse"><a id="402" class="dropdown-item" href="#">TV CATEGORIES<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="test" data-id="20"><a id="403"  class="dropdown-item" href="#">LED TV</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```js
$(document).on('click', '.test', function () {
  var newids=$(this).data('id');
  $(this).parents().children('#'+newids).addClass("active");
 });
```

```css
.active{
color:red !important; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="dropdown"><a id="20" class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle " href="#"> ALL CATEGORIES<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li class="dropdown-submenu dropdown-reverse"><a id="402" class="dropdown-item" href="#">TV CATEGORIES<i class="fas fa-caret-down"></i></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li class="test" data-id="20"><a id="403"  class="dropdown-item" href="#">LED TV</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please take the time to describe what the issues are and why this solution helps. Remember, we're here to educate people, not just dump code on them.

Comment: Hello, if i click ALL CATEGORIES or LED TV it must be add active class to ALL CATEGORIES, yours set active to TV CATEGORIES  BUT, it is a dynamic menu, also need take ids dynamic.

Comment: ok now i am add data attribute to make all category dynamic so it working dynamically for you may be it work for you

Comment: if page refresh active class is gone, do you have a solution for this?